# asp.net Load Child page only from parent page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two pages MainPage.aspx and ChildPage.aspx. From main page when i click a button i redirect to ChildPage.
If i give the address of ChildPage directly on browser, i do not want to load it directly instead i want to redirect to MainPage.
the ChildPage must be loaded only if it is loaded from the MainPage.
How do I find from where the ChildPage.aspx is loaded. how to find the parent page of it or from where it is loaded.

can we try something in the below code

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   if (finding_source)
   {
       Response.Redirect("MainPage.aspx");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath` to see the previous page.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
   if (Request.UrlReferrer != null && Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath == "/MainPage")
   {
     //do what you want
   }else{
      Response.Redirect("~/MainPage.aspx");
   }
}
```

**TIP** But be careful with using it with postbacks since it will change the value of Request.UrlReferrer to the current page during a postback.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is not clear , here i am trying to give my solution.

MAINPAGE.ASPX BUtton Click

```
 protected void lnkRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Session["MainPage"] = "true";//Encrypt it if u wish
Response.Redirect("childpage.aspx");
}
```

CHILDPAGE.ASPX PAGE LOAD

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["MainPage"] as string) && Session["MainPage"].Tostring()=="true")
            {
//proceed
}
else
{
 Response.Redirect("mainpage.aspx");
}
}
```

GLOBAL.ASAX

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Clear();

        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
```

it is little difficult to  control browser shutdown or close...but you can workaround global asax file when your application shutsdown.

Comment: i cannot keep a session variable. if i close the tab or browser the session variable will have the values and if i type ChildPage address in the browser, it will validate value from session variable and childpage will be loaded

Comment: to be clear, I want to load ChildPage only from redirection of MainPage and not by typing ChildPage.aspx link address in the browser